# Narrowing conversion from double to float: is overflow behaviour guaranteed?

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point

If I try this

```
float f = (float)numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
```

Or indeed, try to cast anything bigger than float max down to a float, am I guaranteed to end up with infinity?

It works on GCC, but is it a standard though?

Comment: "Downcasting" is the term used for casting from a base class to a derived class. What you really mean is "narrowing conversion".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> `float f = (float)numeric_limits<double>::infinity();`

This is guaranteed to set `f` to infinity if your compilation platform offers IEEE 754 arithmetic for floating-point computations (it usually does).

> Or indeed, try to cast anything bigger than float max down to a float, am I guaranteed to end up with infinity?

No. In the default IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode, a few `double` values above the maximum finite `float` (that is, `FLT_MAX`) convert to `FLT_MAX`. The exact limit is the number midway between `FLT_MAX` (`0x1.fffffep127` in C99 hexadecimal representation) and the next `float` number that could be represented if the exponent in the single-precision format had a larger range, `0x2.0p127`. The limit is thus `0x1.ffffffp127` or approximately 3.4028235677973366e+38 in decimal.

Comment: In round-to-nearest mode with IEEE 754 arithmetic (which are common).

Comment: In the parlance of this answer, a “few” is 536 million, 870 thousand, 911.

Comment: I think Pascal meant between `0x1.fffffep127` and `0x1.00000p128`. But I think he accidentally increased both the mantissa and the exponent.

Comment: @MarkLakata Indeed. I meant all values to have the same exponent for clarity (changing now).

Answer (score 7):

From the C++11 standard, §4.8.1:

> A prvalue of floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of
>   another floating point type. If the source value can be exactly
>   represented in the destination type, the result of the conversion is
>   that exact representation. If the source value is between two adjacent
>   destination values, the result of the conversion is an
>   implementation-defined choice of either of those values. Otherwise,
>   the behavior is undefined.

This implies that

- If you cast double infinity to float, you get float infinity.
- If you cast a double value, that lies between float max and infinity, to float, then you get float max or float infinity.

Comment: The first part of the question is about infinity, which can be exactly represented in the destination type, no?

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq: I have revised the answer.

Comment: @user763305 That's an interesting interpretation; I'd never thought of it, but you're right: values greater than `FLT_MAX` are between `FLT_MAX` and `Inf`, so the behavior is well defined by the standard.  (Even if it weren't, of course, it's defined by IEEE.)